# Cannot create docker image `The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I tried to create a docker image and it faild during build, I've got the following error:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:latest
 ---> f217490678d7
Step 2/9 : COPY . .
 ---> d7b407250c54
Step 3/9 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Running in 9dfcc0d0306a
Removing intermediate container 9dfcc0d0306a
 ---> fb2d3168cd01
Step 4/9 : ENV LANG C.UTF-8
 ---> Running in c3352f09c416
Removing intermediate container c3352f09c416
 ---> 88968b32256b
Step 5/9 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 ---> Running in 195701bfea20
Removing intermediate container 195701bfea20
 ---> 123d2221d9d0
Step 6/9 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in 13e9a942aef2
hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 13e9a942aef2288aa3a68413bb26d10287017ad239c41eeb4db29d219421bbd9: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"13e9a942aef2288aa3a68413bb26d10287017ad239c41eeb4db29d219421bbd9","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\13e9a942aef2288aa3a68413bb26d10287017ad239c41eeb4db29d219421bbd9","Layers":[{"ID":"5db65963-fe5e-5b74-886b-9c7b310801e9","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\562b238e1af8bfb0a75a9d0ffe7bd2b6b5017e1c49cfdd677849889021f3c299"},{"ID":"bd0ca529-a05f-598e-88ec-8669619a499c","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\5e82be8223c79e65ce9a2339d940627811a5d838d0b1e5cb67364adfd75378ad"},{"ID":"bf32572d-0cf6-5f67-ad88-0cc540fcfeec","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\72813369b8a9eff1a2298ce2d298968c86aac697330fc6bf3a06fbaf0cfbe8e7"},{"ID":"841757cf-5bd7-5064-a186-aefa9646ea2c","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\6cd01bdb1758eabc89a410b8a3cd2eac929cb8589fb3ba79eb9ace0eb1c596c0"},{"ID":"12e55f49-d266-5929-8439-551e64bc8014","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\7edc215be00713436e1b599359c81ca37dee7071919154d4b9027cfe495db865"},{"ID":"42594e61-5ccc-53e4-a75e-c2b4b8b81f49","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\6e8c0a6a096cc11fe30dba98e956b992642f807c2a63924fb5e2ae5dd81a7d91"},{"ID":"ebe10469-6e5d-5cb9-8e9e-23707fce45ef","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\a3a2e977c33e522b1f3deab7990fa4b734241e6ce81017d351d817daaf6a2b2b"},{"ID":"4b7b9b32-ea3a-5864-932b-a842b1353507","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\f5d03c5b12a977abf8f8e0404f31bb6436c82698903bf6d53c31f389e7e951bf"},{"ID":"d4d64c8a-e7a5-5400-a054-3293a86b81b6","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\ac14a4f0395acf4b5ff4ea644c93b5ca059e482ca1a137db1737365fddf9c921"},{"ID":"f5401c4f-68a9-5010-a797-b9dd0d9c2ddc","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\715ac28ba185db9a2f92eedcbc676a0d9e9cbbd088d6f02d8934528191cf8e51"},{"ID":"9f4b9e90-45ec-5926-ae76-f43d1a4e3f9b","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\ba7ea61543d226ac63d67135d5cebd0578c74feeee6a11122e5fb54c7cc5dbfb"},{"ID":"520259ab-2cbd-58a4-8fce-e401b612992a","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\03cb8025e237b6fe5f4197abd512b7b8ed3855b63218cafdacfafa6bbde19bfe"},{"ID":"ac85b7d1-9414-5f90-a32a-f4e57a800f89","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\f75b90b99b5bb7601dd64d939af09cf09847ba094ff65524380ab8691b8d2f30"},{"ID":"7a85de04-87a8-5644-8273-829adfbe6dd5","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\8cf1f577ca553e5223610fda2df390adf9a9e97a75f1461d820ea804778f755f"},{"ID":"a0a3d59d-06ea-591d-bfa4-5574a924a0f1","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\0fb704b6293cb60bf016be930b7daa95366c6a54d3a220eb43308b98e8421780"}],"HostName":"13e9a942aef2","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["C009C05E-56A7-4DB1-B693-D41E55F21044"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\8cf1f577ca553e5223610fda2df390adf9a9e97a75f1461d820ea804778f755f\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true})
```

how can I fix it?
and also, the build took hours to get this error, can I continue it from where it faild? or I need to start from the beginning?

thank you

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3126?

Comment: @funnydman no, il check it now, thanks!

Comment: @funnydman also, how can I continue the build from where it stopped? it took hours to fail and I want to wait again only for it to fail at the same spot

Comment: I don't know it takes _hours_, because it shouldn't. In the next build(without option --no-cache) Docker will use cache where possible.